# « On a » vs « On a que »

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, mathématiques

En mathématiques il est fréquent d'utiliser les tournures « on a » et « on a que » avant d'introduire un résultat. Est-ce que l'une est à privilégier ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« On a que » n'est pas une expression correcte. À l'oral, on confondra « on a que » et « on n'a que », alors que la forme « on a » est bien plus simple.

C'est la justification la plus simple qui me vienne à l'esprit, avec la vision de mon professeur de Maths Spé reprenant chaque élève commençant une phrase par « on a que ».

Comment: Merci pour le feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne trouve nulle part « on a que » dans la littérature, ni chez Bourbaki, ni chez Serre.

Answer (score 0):

On a indique la quantité que tu possèdes.
On n'a que indique la quantité que tu possèdes mais avec l'idée que tu aurais pu avoir plus.

On a sept pommes.
On n'a que sept pommes. (indique que tu aurais pu potentiellement en avoir dix par exemple).

Comment: Je suis francophone : je connais bien la distinction entre « on a » et « on n'a que ». La question considérait « on a que » et non « on n'a que ».

Comment: Au temps pour moi, je pensais à une faute de frappe.